# Matlab: about default value(s) returned by a matlab function with multiple return values?

Tags: matlab

To define a function with multiple return values it should be like

```
function [x, y] = name_function(a, b, c)
```

So when I call the function, normally I will use

```
[x, y] = name_function(a, b, c)
```

But what if I used

```
z = name_function(a, b, c)
```

What would z be?
I tried and it is x got returned. So I think if I use the grammar like this, it will always get the first return value, am I right? Any reference?

It seems not like that. Because

```
d = eig(A)
[V,D] = eig(A)
```

How can I know how to make sure about this when I define a function in Matlab?

Comment: The key to understanding the difference is that functions can query the number of output arguments expected and do different things, including returning different arguments in a different order. See `nargout`.

Comment: oh thank you! That's the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it will always returns the first value. To read on, check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/function-input-and-output-arguments.html#f2-1000057).

But, as @JoshG79 pointed out, functions can query the number of function output arguments and perform differently. Check out [doc:`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. But how about this function in matlab?

d = eig(A)

[V,D] = eig(A)